# Python leaderboard - Add text only in top 3 scores

Tags: python, discord.py, leaderboard

Im making a leaderboard for my discord server. Here is the code:

```
scores_tuples = []
  for member in ctx.guild.members:
      name, score = member.name.split()[0], len(member.roles)-1
      scores_tuples.append((name,score))
  scores_tuples.sort(key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
  for i, (name, score) in enumerate(scores_tuples[:3]):
      await ctx.send(f"★ {name} {score}")
```

I want to make the top 3 scores to have a star next to them and the rest 7 of them to have a number next to them i tried this:

```
for i, (name, score) in enumerate(scores_tuples[:3]):
      await ctx.send(f"★ {name} {score}")
for i, (name, score) in enumerate(scores_tuples[:7]):
      await ctx.send(f"i+4 {name} {score}")
```

But it didn't work, can you help me figure it out?

Comment: What is the error it raises, or what is the output if it works but not correctly?

Comment: The output print the same persons again like:

Comment: ★ testuser1
★ testuser2
★ testuser3
4. testuser1
5. testuser2
6. testuser3

Answer (score 3):

The first detail I can see is in the last line. i+4 is part of the string, not a calculated value. Do {i+4} for this one to get the right value.

The duplicate names are because you are filtering the first 3, and then you filter the first 7.

For the snippet you want `scores_tuples[:3]` and `scores_tuples[3:10]`

Also, there is no need to do two loops:

```
for i, (name, score) in enumerate(scores_tuples[:10]):
  if i < 3:
      await ctx.send(f"★ {name} {score}")
  else:
       await ctx.send(f"{i} {name} {score}")
```

Comment: yes i know was a mistake {i+1} but thats not the problem